# Can't make my laptop not wake up on lid open

Tags: suspend, laptop, acpi

I want my laptop not to wake up when the lid is opened. I have found that it is possible by echoing "LID" or "LID0" into `/proc/acpi/wakeup`. However, there are no such lines in that file and echoing them doesn't add them. There is however a file `/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state` that just says `state: open` when I read it. Are there any ways to disable wakeup on lid opening?

Comment: you can begin to see how your BIOS is configured, there is few options about that

Comment: @damadam I didn't find any lid or acpi related things in the bios

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 20.10. Did you find any solution?